# How to prevent a custom LWC lookup component to be updated

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, read-only, edit

I currently have a LWC in which I render a table with a custom LWC lookup field. How can I make this lookup field uneditable. Is there a syntax or CSS is can use to accomplish this since I currently also use this component when adding new rows to the table

My Current component looks like

```
  <td data-label="Name">
                                        <c-custom-lookup-lwc icon-name="standard:user" s-object-api-name="user" label=""
                                            default-record-id={oppSpl.SplitOwnerId} placeholder="Search People..." slds-button="false">
                                        </c-custom-lookup-lwc>
                                        </td>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with doing a soql with SplitOwner.Name and in template simply do {oppSpl.SplitOwner.Name}

Answer (score 1):

Go to the customLookup component and check whether you find the "input" element inside that. Add the "disabled" attribute to that and pass the "true/false" from parent component or if you need to disabled it always set as disabled="true" .

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This solution seems not to be applicable for a lookup field and has been reported as an issue.